# How to get the absolute path of a file in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, path

I am using Symfony2 framework and I placed 2 pdf files in the doc folder (beside app and web folders)

In my controller I wrote this :

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../doc/" . $filename . '.pdf';
```

I debug the project and I have inside the variable $path:

```
c:/wamp/www/myproject/app/../doc/myfile.pdf
```

Taking this path and putting it in the windows system explorer I can open the file. (so it seems to be good)

But inside the controller whatever function I called on $path returns null, for example mime_content_type() or basename() and if I write file_get_content($path), it says that the file does not exist.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you try with : $path = dirname($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()) . "/doc/" . $filename . '.pdf'; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$path = realpath($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../doc/" . $filename . '.pdf');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

EDIT: realpath also check if path exists. So it could be used only on existing part of path.